# Custom Session save

Tags: android, session, exception, sharedpreferences, runtimeexception

Hi stackoverflow again,

I want to store the session, but I have a problem, I jump an error
I have class "Session" and another class called "MainActivity"

In my Session I have :

```
public void saveSession(Context ctx,String username, String password){
    sharedpreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    String u = username;
    String p = password;
    editor.putString(name, u);
    editor.putString(pass, p);
    editor.commit();
}
```

And in my Main have :

```
session.saveSession(getApplicationContext(), username.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString());
```

I get this error :

```
03-12 01:47:01.648: E/AndroidRuntime(3395): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-12 01:47:01.648: E/AndroidRuntime(3395): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.xx/com.example.xx.UserList}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-12 01:47:01.648: E/AndroidRuntime(3395):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
```

Update: onCreate() method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.user_list); 
//loadSesion(); session.loadSession(getApplicationContext());
usernameSession = session.getUsernameSession(); 
passwordSession = session.getPasswordSession(); 
inicializeBdSqlite();
inicialize(); 
user_list.setOnItemClickListener(this); 
}
```

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.user_list);
  //loadSesion();
  session.loadSession(getApplicationContext());
  usernameSession = session.getUsernameSession();
  passwordSession = session.getPasswordSession();
  inicializeBdSqlite();
  inicialize();
  user_list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
 }

Comment: My method in Session is to simple, I don't understand why not work ..  public void loadSession(Context ctx){
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
  usernameSession = sharedPreferences.getString("name", "");
  passwordSession  = sharedPreferences.getString("pass", "");
 }

Comment: Solved I not instanciated session, I'm a stupid Thanks Mikey you are great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, about the `SharedPreferences` and the way you are using it. I have some notes:

1) Make sure that the strings `name` and `pass` are final string and already initialized in the class that this method is inside because if any of your `sharedPreference` keys are `null` the whole file may be broke as following:

```
final string name = "name";
final string pass = "password";
```

2)No need to put the new values into new strings, pass it directly

```
public void saveSession(Context ctx,String username, String password){
SharedPreference sharedpreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString(name, username);
editor.putString(pass, password);
editor.commit();
}
```

3)Make your `getter` methods as following:

```
public String getUserName(Context ctx){
SharedPreference sharedpreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
return sharedpreferences.getString(name, "");//"" is the default value
}
```

4)About the `user_list` line `user_list.setOnItemClickListener(this);` .Make sure that your Main activity `implements` the class `OnClickListener` as following:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
```

and in your `MainActivity` override it as following:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) { 
       //You action
}
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Tamawy, you when instansiate in the main of this form "Session session = new Session()" always that load the Main, ALWAYS, but ALWAYS create a new object, independent of the previous "www.tcl.tk/man/java1.2.6/TclJava/JavaNewCmd.html"  , NOT work remember ;) , is a bad logic create a custom sharedpreferences, of my point of view

Comment: I don`t understand what you are trying to say

Comment: usually when you start to study java, not as is your education, but if you remember, whenever you make a "new" create an object, that is to say when you throw the main, call the "new", creating another object independently of preview,that is, a new reference, is basic, but thanks for you help